# Nested Protocols are not checked by Mypy/Pylance

Tags: python, types, mypy, pylance

I'm using Protocols to define some base classes
I want to just inherit the parent Protocol and have the children type checked automatedly.

Here is the example code:

```py
class Child(Protocol):
   name: str


class Parent(Protocol):
   Child: Child


class FooBar(Parent):
   class Child:
       pass
       # No Error
```

Why is Mypy/Pylance not inferring that the `Child` Protocol requires a `name`

Comment: `Child: Child` in `Parent` means "an instance attribute called `Child` that's of type `Child`. `class Child:` in `FooBar` is creating a new nested class that just happens to have the same name as the outer `Child`, and that's not what the `Parent` protocol is checking for.

Comment: I don't actually know if it's possible to use a `Protocol` to verify the existence of a nested class that has a certain name. Maybe `Child: ClassVar[Type[Child]]` in `Parent`? That's just a guess though.

Comment: `Protocol` is not meant to be used to specify base classes; use `ABC` for that. Also, Pylance is a [language server](https://github.com/microsoft/language-server-protocol), not a type checker; [Pyright](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright) is what it uses under the hood, which [should have emitted an error](https://pyright-play.net/?strict=true&code=GYJw9gtgBALgngBwJYDsDmUkQWEMoAK4MYAxmADYBQNpFAhgM6NQDCAFkhQCYAURYEuQoBKAFxUoUlPQgBTMVEYwQNKnSYsC9EHJQx%2BxMpXGSpHLt0UWeajcygAxMGABCO-jr0xTUqPZYbKzM-KQRNKiA) with `--strict` specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known limitation in `mypy`, here's the corresponding [issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/14767). As pointed out in comments, Pyright detects this type violation correctly. If you define the type externally and assign, `mypy` also [identifies](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=5729deecf2e71ab7cd7d6cb6cc19a650) the error:

```py
from typing import Protocol


class Child(Protocol):
   name: str

class Parent(Protocol):
   Child: Child

class _Child:
    pass

class FooBar(Parent):
    Child = _Child  # E: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "type[_Child]", base class "Parent" defined the type as "Child")  [assignment]
```